# Issue while opening external program in PHP

Tags: php, apache, cmd, xampp

I have created a program using PHP in which there is event on button click to open PDF using FoxIT Reader. For just one PDF its working well for a single user. I installed this on server and I have multiple users on server, for example: `[(administrator -- user-1), (sam -- user-2), (mac -- user-3)]` and so one.

1. I start my xampp using `user-1` .
2. I start my application in localhost (`localhost/myapplication/index.php`)
3. When I click on button I am executing following command to open pdf:

**PHP code:**

```
$cmdpdf = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" '.
$pdfnameinTempdeudPDF.'';
    shell_exec($cmdpdf);
```

It open PDF for `user-1` his current screen using FoxIT Reader.

For `user-2`

1. There is no need to start xampp as its alredy started by `user-1`
2. I start my application in localhost (`localhost/myapplication/index.php`)(using different session with login)
3. When I click on button then its opens PDF in `user-1` screen.

Can you please help me in that?

Comment: Because the Apache instance is running as a service for user-1.

Comment: Why are you trying to do it? Won't using the browser to read PDF save you a lot of headaches?

Comment: @AlanMachado is there any solution for this?

Comment: I am developed that using php (browser) :( so i have to do that...

Comment: Despite being a PHP code, I think that question belongs to Server Fault.

Comment: still there is no solution for my problem  :(